# Android : Show Notification in Watch When Any Call or Social Network notification of mobile?(using Bluetooth)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, android-bluetooth

- I  want to do this But don't have idea how it apply / implement.

If any  incoming or misses calls, Voicemail or GMail or sms alerts, calendar reminders, Facebook chats & posts on the Mobile ( Android 4.3/4.4) show it's Notification in Watch.

eg. If in Mobile Get New Mail then that notification alert show on watch screen.(using Bluetooth)

[For Better Understand See This Link or Video](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.connected.life)

guide me how to achive this.If possible give example of it.
 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per the product information, it uses BT LE . BT LE has many profiles/services running(check [link](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BLE.aspx) ) .